# How to define Sets in scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm having trouble using my member? function. I need to recurse on my set? function until the last element in my list 'lst' is reached. I believe I have the navigation down correctly, but maybe my inputs syntax is wrong. I know there are three cases:

1) What happens if the list is empty? that means that there aren't any duplicates in it
2) What happens if the current element of the list exists somewhere in the rest of the list? then it means that there's a duplicate in the list (hint: the member procedure might be useful)
3) If none of the above are true, continue with the next element.

Here is my code.

```
(define (member? e lst)
(if (null? lst) #f 
(if (equal? e (car lst)) #t
(member? e (cdr lst)))))

(define (set? lst)      
(if (null? lst) #t                 ;Case1
(if (member? (car lst) lst) #f     ;Case2
(set? (cdr lst)))))                ;Case3

;Example tests for the set? function
(set? '(x y z))
(set? '(a 1 b 2 c 3))
(set? '())
(set? '(6 2 2))
(set? '(x y z x))
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a small mistake with your code, look how it gets fixed:

```
(define (set? lst)      
  (if (null? lst)
      #t
      (if (member? (car lst) (cdr lst)) ; in here
          #f
          (set? (cdr lst)))))
```

In particular, notice what this line is doing:

```
(member? (car lst) lst)
```

That won't work: the test is checking whether the first element in `lst` is a member of `lst` - and that'll always be true. The solution is simple, just check to see if the current element is in the *rest* of the list, if it's there, then we know that we've found a duplicate:

```
(member? (car lst) (cdr lst))
```

And by the way, the above code would look much nicer using `cond`, which is great when you have nested `if`s:

```
(define (set? lst)      
  (cond ((null? lst) #t)
        ((member? (car lst) (cdr lst)) #f)
        (else (set? (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: Now could also be the ideal time to explain to the OP why `cond` is so much better than nested `if`s. :-P

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young you got it :)